# IE and Firefox need different values for margin?

Tags: html, css

A quick question about CSS, I have the following ugly code (CSS is in there in style tags temporarily, until I put it in the .css file as it should be):

```
<ol style="margin-left: 0; padding-left: 0; ">
    <li style="margin-left: 1em;"><spring:message code="message1"/></li>
    .....
</ol>
```

When I test this code in Firefox, I get the right alignment, but when I test it in IE (I am using 8 right now), it doesn't align the same way. To get it to look the same in IE, I need to use

```
<li style="margin-left: 2em;">
```

which of course does not look good with Firefox.

Does anyone know why do IE and Firefox need a different value for margin?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: IE 8 standards mode or IE 8 quirks mode?

Comment: That's widely known as the box model bug: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug - Are using strict mode for your website?

Comment: The box model bug... You should use a specific stylesheet for IE8 to avoid this.

Comment: @Siyah — Nonsense. You should use a standards mode triggering Doctype.

Comment: I'd use a specific stylesheet to be sure of avoiding the problem.

Comment: @Siyah — A standards mode triggering Doctype is sure to avoid the problem in everything newer then IE 5.5.

Comment: Maybe you don’t even need a “different” value for `margin`, but just to simply equalize the possibly different default `paddings` as well.

Comment: `list-style-position: outside !important;` to `ul` solved it for me once

Comment: @Quentin Thanks, that was good to know! I use standards mode now, IE8 and Chrome 36 work but not Firefox (I use 32).

Comment: Why are u targeting IE 8 in the first place? It is really needed? Right now the latest IE version should be 11 and I think we are close for version 12 to be released.

Comment: That's the requirement that I've got, it should support IE 8 and higher. Wouldn't bother with IE8 otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you want a CSS answer, you can use `box-sizing`. I came across this and I am pretty sure that you will get the same output. You just need to make the other browsers act the same as IE 8 and put in `box-sizing: border-box;`. [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp).